# Why do WebKit browsers not render this definition list the same way as Gecko, Presto, and Trident?

Tags: css, webkit

When I use this HTML:

```html
<dl>
    <dt>term</dt>
    <dd>description</dd>
    <dt>term</dt>
    <dd>description</dd>
</dl>
```

And this CSS:

```css
dl, dt, dd {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
dt, dd {
    display: inline;
}
dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}
dt:before {
    display: block;
    content: "separator";
    font-weight: normal;
}
dt:after {
    content: ":";
}
dd {
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
```

WebKit renders it like this:
[image: WebKit's rendering]

But Firefox 3.5 and above, Opera 10 and above (I haven't tested below 10), and Internet Explorer 8 and above render it like this:
[image: Gecko rendering]

It seems as if WebKit ignores the `display: block;` of `dt:before`.

**[Try it yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/J7nWv/)**

What causes this behavior, and how can I get WebKit's result to look like the other browsers' results?

Comment: I wouldn't rule out the possibility of a bug. They stack in an even more interesting way, yet oh so consistently across all browsers, when you turn the `display: inline` into a `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Reading [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html) this seems like a bug in WebKit: "The :before and :after pseudo-elements interact with other boxes as if they were real elements inserted just inside their associated element."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a webkit bug but I've gotten it to render correctly using the code [listed here.](http://jsfiddle.net/J7nWv/1/) Basically, I changed block to 'inline-block' and gave it a width of 100%.

Comment: Hmm. This seems to work fairly well when `:before` has `content`, but once I set `content` to be empty (`content: "";`) it still takes up a one-line space (in all browsers) and it doesn't seem to respond to `height`, `line-height`, or `font-size` in any of the browsers.

Comment: Are you setting that content dynamically? Can you use different classes for when you do and don't have content? The reason it keeps the spacing is because you're forcing chrome to apply the block in the inline-block statement.

Comment: No, it is not dynamic. There is never going to be any `content` in `:before`; I was just using it to help illustrate the problem in the question.